# Not-line oriented diff

Tags: css, diff

I have two CSS files where most of the whitespace have been removed. I wonder whether there's a way to get a meaningful diff out of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run each file through a CSS prettifier, and then diff them the normal way.

A quick google search turned up this online prettifier: http://procssor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Do a search and replace through the css file and insert a new line after every '{', '}' and ';' character. Then, you can use ordinary diff to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/?l=css).  That tool is a language aware diff tool, so trivial things like white space and comments are filtered out as false positives.